# Flutter: How to solve value type Object can't be assigned to Map<String, dynamic> on streambuilder

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to fetch data from firebase and displaying the data into a listtile, but Im getting an error when trying to map the documents data into a list to display its contents

[image]

Here's my code

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: users.snapshots(),
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return const Center(
                      child: Text("Something went wrong"),
                    );
                  }

                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return const Center(
                      child: Text("Loading"),
                    );
                  }

                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return CustomScrollView(
                      slivers: [
                        SliverList(
                          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                            snapshot.data!.docs.map(
                              (DocumentSnapshot document) {
                                Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()!;
                                return ListTile(
                                  onTap: () => callChatDetailsScreen(
                                      context, data['name'], data['uid']),
                                  title: Text(data['name']),
                                  subtitle: Text(data['status']),
                                );
                              },
                            ).toList(),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    );
                  }
                  return Container();
                })
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Share DocumentSnapshot class code

Comment: @amir_a14 I don't have a DocumentSnapshot class in my files. Do I need to create one? I used to think it comes in when you add firestore dependencies

Comment: @amir_a14 It's part of cloud_firestore package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
(DocumentSnapshot document) {
```

into this:

```
(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>> document) {
```

[`data()`](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/lib/src/document_snapshot.dart) returns a value of type `T` and the class `DocumenSnapshot` is declared in this way: `abstract class DocumentSnapshot<T extends Object?>`, therefore if you don't specify a type for `DocumentSnapshot` then `data()` will return a value of type `Object`.